# sdk Facebook no redirecciona a la url de inicio de sesion

Tags: react-native

Estoy tratando de colocar un botón de inicio de sesión con facebook , en React-Native.

El botón funciona si tengo instalada la app de Facebook, pero si no esta instalada no redirecciona a la pagina web de facebook y aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.- Esta es la configuración de acceso a web en facebook.developers:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Aqui solo me falta agregar la ruta de mainactivity, pero no se como colocar la ruta aqui, en mi caso la ruta que tengo en mi ordenador es la siguiente `C:\Users\edm\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\music\android\app\src\main\java\com\music\MainActivity.java`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es dejar instalada la app porque borrarla? ademas te sirve y todo aqui te dejo la ruta modificada para que compruebes :3 C:\Users\edm\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\music\androide\app/MainActivity\dgc\main\java\com\photos\.java

Comment: el problema es que si la aplicación la ocupa un usuario que no tenga la App, le arrojara el error, y no lo rediccionara a la web de facebook